# Django AWS S3 Files Not Showing Up on Site

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

When I check the page source, the link is linking to the correct AWS links but no images/css or media files are showing up. The bucket policy and CORS are configured as it should according to the tutorials I've followed. The bucket has the mdeia and static folders inserted as well.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'XXX'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ckeditor',
    'django_cleanup',
    'storages',
]
```

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the browser developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got is incomplete. You need something like this:

Create aws folder next to your settings.py with __init__.py and the following files:

conf.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = {BUCKET_NAME}
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = '{appname}.settings.aws.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

storage_backends.py:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

then import it into your settings.py/production settings file:

```
from .aws.conf import *
```