# Why is my Django app not formatted using AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have configured **AWS S3** to handle the static files and I can see the static folder in my bucket and also its sub-folders such as admin. I don't know what is wrong and why it is not formatting the site with **css**, **images** and **videos** I have in my static file.

[the static folder was added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mayT.jpg)

So why can't I see any effect in the site?

this what i have

```
     DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
     AWS_STORAGE_BUCKE_NAME = 'maha2022'
     AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazoneaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
     AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
     #AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = ''

     AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
     STATICFILES_DIRS = [

       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
     ]

     STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
     STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

     MEDIA_URL = 'cart/images/'
     MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/cart/images')
```

Comment: Have you checked that these variables match what you have defined in S3?
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

Comment: i updated the post to include what i have done in settings.py. i also added storages in the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: i see in aws s3 the resource name
'arn:aws:s3:::maha2022/static/'
is this the reason?

Comment: i went to the webpage and i tried to see from where it is getting the photos and sure enough the link points to the bucket url but the photos are not shown. why is that? here is the link "https://bucketname.s3.amazoneaws.com/static/..."

Comment: I found the solution after I read the below post.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960479/django-aws-s3-files-not-showing-up-on-site)

Comment: I found the solution from other post [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960479/django-aws-s3-files-not-showing-up-on-site)